# git uppercase name of branch

Tags: git, git-config

In specific project the word "feature" pass to uppercase.

```
For example:
git checkout -b "feature/#123123-test"

the name of branch will:
FEATURE/#123123-teste

if I put:
git checkout -b "otherthing/#123123-test"

will:
otherthing/#123123-test
```

.gitconfig:

```
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[user]
    name = Bruno
    email = *******@******.com.br
```

Anyone know what happened here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a case insensitive file system such as Windows;

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Init."
[master (root-commit) 69082bb] Init.

$ git checkout -b FEATURE/first
Switched to a new branch 'FEATURE/first'

$ git checkout -b feature/second
Switched to a new branch 'feature/second'

$ git branch
 FEATURE/first
 FEATURE/second
 master
```

Your branches are stored as files and directories that contain the commit hash they point to. When you create a "branch folder" it only gets created once and will always have that casing.

Take a look in `.git/refs/heads` to see the case for your repo.

Comment: thanks, I take a look at find .git/refs/heads ands me first head "feature" is "FEATURE"

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the issue... the branch prefix is being converted to uppercase.

Comment: It wasn't an issue. It's one of the warts of git's UI / implementation. Now that the wart is better understood it'll be possible to work around it in the future. For instance by not creating "branch folders" with different casing etc.

Comment: Work like a charm. Change folder name and it fixed. You saved me <3